# Use a sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Consider the numerical 20 questions game. In this game, player 1 thinks of a number in the range 1 to n. Player 2 has to figure out this number by asking the fewest number of true/false questions.Assume that nobody cheats.
i. What is an optimal strategy if n in known?
ii. What is a good strategy is n is not known?

Comment: That is called binary search in CS terms.

Comment: or [Dichotomic search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search)

Comment: Binary search if `n` is known, otherwise the problem becomes more interesting.

Comment: @IVlad if upper bound is unknown, first doubling from 1(to find a upper bound), then halving(to find the exact number).

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to this wiki: [binary search for number guessing game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Number_guessing_game).

If n is known, use binary search algorithm to find it, so asked questions is not more than `floor(log2(n))`.

If n is unknown, you can first find an upper bound by repeated doubling, then apply binary search. It's clear that asked questions is not more than `2 * floor(log2(k)) + 1`, where k is the unknown selected number.

Comment: yeah! thanks for that! but in the question, it says that, it should be done in Optimal and in Good strategy!! :(

Comment: I updated my answer to give the time complexity for both cases. They are proved to be optimal and surely good strategies.